# Parsing multiple templates with data

Tags: templates, go

How do i pass the data to the right template?

I have the following templates and want to parse them

layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        ...
        </header>
        <main>
            {{template "main"}}
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

list.html:

```
{{define "main"}}
{{range $index, $element := . }}    
    <div>
        <a href=#>{{ $element.Data1 }}</a>
        <p>{{ $element.Data2 }}</p>
        <p>{{ $element.Data3 }}</p>
    </div>
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

When i use this in the handler func only the "main" template is executed and i dont get the layout.

```
t, err := template.ParseFiles(layoutPath, templatePath)

t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "main", Data)
```

And with this i dont have the Data in the list template and so cant display the list.

```
t, err := template.ParseFiles(layoutPath, templatePath)

t.ExecuteTemplate(w, Data)
```

So how do i execute this properly?

Comment: The answer from mkopriva solves my problem! I edited the list.html so now it should be proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions):

> {{template "name" pipeline}} The template with the specified name is
>   executed with dot set to the value of the pipeline.

This means that to pass data from the `layout.html` template to the `list.html` template you need to pass the data as the second argument of the `template` action.

E.g. `{{template "main" .}}`